# How to improve my GeoPoint ElasticSearch Index for better response time?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Below is my Index (tz_geo) and mapping details:

**Index setting:**

```
{
  "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": "false",
  "index.priority": "1",
  "index.query.default_field": [
    "*"
  ],
  "index.write.wait_for_active_shards": "1",
  "index.refresh_interval": "30s",
  "index.number_of_replicas": "7"
}
```

**Mapping:**

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "properties": {     
      "geo": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      },
      "gnameid": {
        "type": "long",
        "index": false
      },
      "iso": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "index": false
      },
      "locid": {
        "type": "long",
        "index": false
      },      
      "tz": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "index": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**ElasticSearch details:**

```
{
  "name" : "node-1",
  "cluster_name" : "test-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "ET-Gwb-iR4mCmzZUppuOKw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.2.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "rpm",
    "build_hash" : "508c38a",
    "build_date" : "2019-06-20T15:54:18.811730Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.0.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

**Number of nodes in cluster:** 11

**Index data size:** 9.6 GB

**Total documents in Index:** 12025944

**My Geo Search using C# ElasticSearch NEST**

```
var result = await ES_Client.SearchAsync<ES_TZGeo>(s => s
                   .Index("tz_geo")                   
                   .Query(query => query.Bool(b => b.Filter(filter => filter
                   .GeoDistance(geo => geo
                       .Field(f => f.geo)
                       .Distance("500km").Location(lat, lon)
                       .DistanceType(GeoDistanceType.Arc)

                   )

                   )

                   )

                )
                   .Sort(sort => sort
                       .GeoDistance(g => g
                           .Field(f => f.geo)
                           .Order(SortOrder.Ascending)
                           .Unit(DistanceUnit.Kilometers)
                           .Points(new GeoLocation(lat, lon))
                           .DistanceType(GeoDistanceType.Arc)))
                           .Size(1)
                   );
```

The above search will find the nearest document based on lat,lon provided.

We are seeing that sometimes the response is more than 1 sec for the above query. Is there any recommendation on how to improve on this search either in terms of NEST or maybe change the replicas, etc?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you know where the time is being spent when it's more than 1 second? It might be worth profiling the app, including network tracing, to ascertain possible causes e.g. GC, load on server, etc.